# pdfx document doesn't compile using ua option

Tags: pdfx, tagged-pdf

I am trying to create accessible pdf document using LaTex, and i am having trouble getting it to run with the accessibility option in pdf-x. According to the documentaiton (http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pdfx/pdfx.pdf) the correct option for an accessible (ie tagged) pdf is "ua" or "ua-1".

This does not work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ua]{pdfx}
\begin{document}
Hello World
\end{document}
```

If i attempt to compile the document (using LuaLatext, Xelatex or Pdflatexmk from texshop) I get and error:

```
 LaTeX Error: Unknown option `ua' for package `pdfx'
```

I have also tried

```
\providecommand{\pdfxopts}{a-1b,ua,allxmp,mathxmp}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[\pdfxopts]{pdfx}
\begin{document}
 Hello World
 \end{document}
```

And that gets the same error as the first example.

On the other hand, other options work but do not generate a tagged pdf.For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}
\begin{document}
Hello World
\end{document}
```

compiles but does not generate a tagged pdf.

Comment: reading the pdf and sample this seems to need a  dual definition of options \providecommand{\pdfxopt}{a-1b,ua-1,allxmp,mathxmp} the ua can be used to replace ua-1 in the above usage

Comment: @KJO thanks for the suggestion! I have tried that (based on page 25 of the documentation) but I get the same error

Comment: your version of pdfx seems to be older, with a current version (2018/11/29 v1.6) the error message is different, but beside this: pdfx doesn't create a tagged pdf, see e.g page 2 of the documentation "By ‘Experimental, not fully implemented’ here we mean primarily that the document structure, as required for ‘Tagged PDF’, is not handled by this package."

Comment: v1.6 General: Added XMP support for PDF/UA-1

Comment: Are you using MiKTeX?  The package there is v1.5.84, not the updated v1.6.  Searching the up-to-date MiKTeX package, I cannot find `\DeclareOption{ua}` or `\DeclareOption{ua-1}`.  But I do find those lines in the up-to-date CTAN package.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you! i have updated to the new version and now get the same error message as you d. Can you clarify what you mean by not fully implemented? Does pdfx produce any sort of tags at all (even if imperfect ones? ) ?

Comment: Imho not, unless something dramatic happened in the new version. If you want to create tags, check the tagpdf package, but be aware that it is experimental, expects you to use luatex and mark up some things manually and quite a number things are still missing (but feedback is welcome).